# How to find all tuples in JavaPairRDD where the key is in a JavaRDD

Tags: java, join, apache-spark, rdd

I have the following rdds

```
JavaPairRDD<String, MyObject> myObjects = //implemented elsewhere
JavaRDD<String> myKeys = //implemented elsewhere
```

I would like to find all tuples in myObjects such that the key of the tuple is present in myKeys. The only way I can think of doing so is by converting myKeys to a JavaPairRDD, then joining myKeys and myObject. So, something like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> myKeysPair = myKeys.mapToPair(t -> new Tuple2<>(t, 0));
JavaRDD<MyObject> myFinalObjects = myObjects.
    join(myKeysPair).mapToPair(t -> t._2).map(t->t._1);
```

This doesn't seem very efficient, and I was wondering if there was a better way of getting what I wanted.

I am using Spark 1.5.2, and Java 8